# Does NFS:Hot Pursuit Autolog need Xbox Live Gold?

Tags: xbox-network, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

Is Xbox Live Gold required to use the Autolog features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires a Live account yes, but not gold. Multiplayer will not be available and some features of autolog might be disables like social sharing etc